# Background image does not go under content div

Tags: html, css, background

I want to put the background image right under .right div but it positions itself just above .right div. How can the problem be solved?

Here's the pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Hilfd

```
.background-image {
    background-image: url("http://www.worldswallpapers.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/Nature-Wallpapers-2014-2.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    display: block;
    filter: blur(5px);
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
    height: 800px;
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
.right {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 400px;
    max-height: auto;   
    z-index: 5;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    background: rgba (255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}
```

Comment: Missing semi-colon: `background-image: url("http://www.worldswallpapers.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/Nature-Wallpapers-2014-2.jpg")` http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mfhaB

Comment: @Shomz I like these kind of problems with a small but crucial syntax. Usually they come when fatigue in the night. :D Thanks, though.

Comment: It happens to everyone :)

Answer (score 0):

It's not just the missing semicolon. ;)

I think that this is desired result:

**The HTML part:**

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="background-image"></div>      
    <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS Styles**

```
.wrap { position: relative; }
.background-image {
    background-image: url("http://www.worldswallpapers.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/Nature-Wallpapers-2014-2.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    filter: blur(5px);
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
    height: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.right {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
    padding: 50px 20px;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 400px;
    max-height: auto;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}
```

End here's the working pen: http://codepen.io/madcorp/pen/jgptv

Answer (score -1):

You are missing the semicolon after the background image url:

```
.background-image {
  background-image: url("http://www.worldswallpapers.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/Nature-Wallpapers-2014-2.jpg");
[other rules...]
}
```